# deleting items from dictionaries

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary

This is my dictionary

```
mydict = {'PENNY': 0, "NICKEL": 0, "DIME": 3, "QUARTER": 5, "HALF DOLLAR": 3, "ONE": 0}
```

It's a dictionary of the change I have in my pocket.

I want come up with way to delete the items from mydict whose values are 0.

I want to change

```
{'PENNY': 0, "NICKEL": 0, "DIME": 3, "QUARTER": 5, "HALF DOLLAR": 3, "ONE": 0}
```

into

```
{"DIME": 3, "QUARTER": 5, "HALF DOLLAR": 3}
```

How do I do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: You should check Python documentation for this.

Answer (score 0):

```
new_dict={ k:v for k, v in mydict.iteritems() if v != 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
print dict(filter(lambda x:x[1] !=0,ab.iteritems()))
```

Output:

```
{'QUARTER': 5, 'HALF DOLLAR': 3, 'DIME': 3}
```

Comment: Don't compare ints with `is`. It doesn't work the way you think it does.

Comment: Oh yes! You are right. Fixed.